# How to implement Azure signalr serverless token based authentication and authorization

Tags: azure, oauth, jwt, signalr, serverless

I have created an azure signalr service with serverless option.
The negotiate function is able to generate JWT token with 'x-ms-client-principal-name' and the connection gets established without issues.
I have referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config and the function is able to send events to a particular userid/groups.
I have been asked to secure the client - server communication.
I am new to security domain. I referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-authenticate-azure-functions this link but I am not able to configure the given sample app and not able to understand the concept.

My scenario is: I have a Client .net web app in which user can login using organization account as well as using google.
This app calls azure signlar negotiate function with userID and the deviceId in which it is interested to receive events through signalR function.
Signalr function gets events from the azure  eventhub trigger and sends it to the groups.

Please help me to increase the security of this application. Is the token received from negotiate function sufficient as far as security is concerned?
Can any unauthorized user connect to my azure subscribeToGroup/sendEvent functions with the acquired jwt token from negotiate?
I am trying to use this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension in which idToken and claimTypeList are additional parameters along with x-ms-client-principal-name(userid). But I am not able to understand this with respect to security. 
The client in this sample is index.html with auth.js. But how it is said to be secure is not understandable.
Please help and direct me for the correct setup and code.